# How to add custom floats to \listoffigures?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I created custom float objects using the `float` package to draw stuff with `tikz`.

```
\usepackage{float}
 \floatstyle{plain}
 \newfloat{tkizfloat}{htb}{lof}
 \floatname{tkizfloat}{Figure}
```

Is there any way of adding custom floats like this one created above to the `\listoffigures` without messing up the existing one?

And how to ensure that the custom float objects are counted the same way like normal figure objects, like that:

```
1.1 Example 1 (figure)
1.2 Example 2 (figure)
1.3 Example 3 (tikzfloat)
1.4 Example 4 (figure)
```

I'm currently adding them simply to the `lof`-file but that's a complete mess. Just see the screenshot below to understand the problems explained above.

[image: screenshot explaining the issue]

Minimal working example for the screenshot above:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
 \floatstyle{plain}
 \newfloat{tkizfloat}{htb}{lof}
 \floatname{tkizfloat}{Figure}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \NewEnviron{elaboration}{
  \par
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[rectangle,minimum width=0.4\textwidth] (m)
   {\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\BODY\end{minipage}};
   \draw[dashed] (m.south west) rectangle (m.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture} }
 \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
 \listoffigures

 \begin{tkizfloat}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=4cm, x=.5cm,font=\sffamily]
   \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (20,0);
   \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (0,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Some Chart}
  \label{tkiz:example}
 \end{tkizfloat}

 \begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example.png}
  \caption{Some Image}
  \label{img:example}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `figure` environment?

Comment: some solutions are too simple to figure out, thanks :)

Comment: A common misconception is that `figure` can contain only `\includegraphics` and, conversely, that `\includegraphics` can only go in a `figure` environment. Both are wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current labelling/numbering scheme is confusing as it is now: you have two floating objects labelled "Figure" but they are numbered independently. Apparently your new float behaves exactly as `figure`, so you can simply use the `figure` environment to wrap your `tikzpicture`; this will solve both the numbering and the LoF issues:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \listoffigures

 \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=4cm, x=.5cm,font=\sffamily]
   \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (20,0);
   \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (0,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Some Chart}
  \label{tkiz:example}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{cat}
  \caption{Some Image}
  \label{img:example}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i feel so stupid right now, i tried so much but i never thought of simply using the exiting figure environment... thanks alot!

Answer (score 12):

In case you *really* want a new float type (say, "Map") that nevertheless should be listed in the List of Figures, here's how to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*{\listfigurename}{List of Figures and Maps}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=lof]{map}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=simple}
\captionsetup[map]{listformat=simple}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@figure}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}}
\renewcommand*{\l@map}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}}
\renewcommand*{\p@figure}{\figurename~}
\renewcommand*{\p@map}{\mapname~}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{map}[ht]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A map}
\end{map}

\end{document}
```

[image]